# Scoping Postgres Queries with a large number of indexes

Tags: sql, postgresql, performance, relational-database

I have a table (let's call it Table A) with about 200 million rows in it. When executing queries, I need to scope the query request based on the caller's authorizations, which is a list of IDs of records they can see. The problem is two-fold:

1. For business-related reasons, the authorization lists cannot be stored in the database and need to be passed in somehow with the query.
2. The size of an authorization list can exceed 100k IDs.

What would be the most performant way to make queries with this authorization scoping? It feels too large for an IN clause, but I could be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a temporary table containing these identifiers and join with that table.  Make sure to `ANALYZE` the table explicitly. to get decent execution plans.

I would run some performance tests if that beats a huge `IN` list. I guess for big lists it will.

I think that there is something wrong in your design if you have to pass huge lists like that. You will never get great performance that way – just having to send this amount of data to the database will take time and tax your network resources, and of course the database also has to digest the data.

Answer (score 0):

PostgreSQL does not implement a hashed (or binary searched) IN-list operation.  If the IN-list occurs as a index condition, it is likely to run fine.  But if it occurs as a filter condition, evaluating whether the IN-list is satisfied for each row will involve iterating over the entire IN-list (if it is not satisfied) or over 1/2 of the IN-list (on average, if it is satisfied), for each row under consideration.  That is going to suck if the number of rows is large.

Writing it as a join to a VALUES-list is syntactically annoying, but it is likely to perform better.  Or as a join to a temp table which you populate and ANALYZE in some previous step.  Or revisit your business-related reasons to see if they can be fixed.

```
select sum(b) from foo where c in (1,8,19/*,...*/)
```

vs

```
select sum(b) from foo join (values (1),(8),(19)/*,...*/) f(x) on c=x
```

Note that performance in general is an area which changes from version to version, so you really should specify your version.  Some hypothetical future version might even implement a hashed IN-list, although I wouldn't hold my breath for that.